# He overcame his defects ________ sheer force of habit

Tags: prepositions

What is the correct preposition to be used in the blank?

Comment: Perhaps you should try posting these on the English Language Learner's Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'Through,' 'by,' or 'with.' 'Through' is the most appropriate, 'with' the least.

Comment: Perhaps. But why?

Comment: Through is the original form of the idiom. Things done forcefully are done "through force" with 'sheer' being a modifier of force. These days, 'by' is more standard since it's the catch-all for "how you do things"  - you do them "BY doing X." The third option is more answering the question "done with what tool?" - "WITH x". But the origin of the phrase was in a time when through was used more, so as an idiom it retains that phrasing despite the evolution of language in general.

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer HTH.